# Can someone please tell me where can i write my bcrypt-hashing function?

Tags: express, mongoose, bcrypt

```js
exports.postLogin = (req, res) => {
  let { email, pass } = req.body;
  console.log(email);

  User.findOne({ email }, (err, result) => {
    console.log(email, pass, result.pass);
    if (err) {
      res.json({ status: 'failed', message: err });
    } else if (!result) {
      res.json({ status: 'failed', message: 'email or password are wrong' });
    } else {
      bcrypt.compare(pass, result.pass).then(async (isPassCorrect) => {
        if (isPassCorrect) {
          const token = await signToken(result.id);
          res.json({
            status: 'success',
            message: 'you logged in !!',
            token,
          });
        } else res.json({ status: 'failed', message: 'email or password are wrong!' });
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quetsion is not really clear about what you are trying to do, so I'm guessing into the black.

If I get you right, you are looking for the right place in order to hash a password before it gets saved, so you can use `bcrypt.compare()` on the encrypted password, is that right?

If yes, you could use mongooses `pre`-hook to hash the password before mongoose actually saves a document. To accomplish this add this to your model file

```
User.pre('save', async function (next) {
    await bcrypt.genSalt(12).then(async salt => {
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt).catch(err => {
            return next(err)
        })
      }).catch(err => {
          return next(err)
    })
})
```